# How do I correct this input for Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

**Cross posted [in Wolfram community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1305268)**.

---

I have the following input:

```
op = I*Nest[op, Ψ[r, ϕ], 3] ==  2 Ψ[r, ϕ]*r^2/Cos[ϕ]^5

 sol = CapitalPsi[r, Phi] /. 
 NDSolve[{op,
 CapitalPsi[0, Phi] == 1,
 Derivative[1, 0][CapitalPsi][0, Phi] == 0, 
 Derivative[2, 0][CapitalPsi][0, Phi] == 10, 
 Derivative[3, 0][CapitalPsi][0, Phi] == 0, 

CapitalPsi[r, 0] == 1, 
 Derivative[0, 1][CapitalPsi][r, 0] == 0},

 CapitalPsi, {r, 0, 3}, {Phi, 0, 3},
 MaxSteps -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 1,
 AccuracyGoal -> 1, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
 "MinPoints" -> 32, "MaxPoints" -> 32, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2},
 Method -> {"Adams", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 1}}] // 

 Plot3D[sol, {r, 0, 3}, {Phi, 0, 3}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

However, it gives an error. Is there an alternative way to solve the given PDE below?

$$i\left[r\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dr}+\tan\phi\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\phi}\right]^3\Psi(r,\phi)=2\Psi(r,\phi)\frac{r^2}{\cos^5 \phi}$$

Comment: The problem is definition of `op`. What is `op` in `Nest`?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci : `op = Function[r*D[#, r] + Tan[\[Phi]] D[#, \[Phi]]];` from:http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1305268

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Aside from issues already mentioned above, your boundary conditions (b.c.) are very suspicious: you're giving 4 b.c.s in $r$ direction and 2 in $\phi$ direction, while in this case we _usually_ need 3 for $r$ and 3 for $\phi$, are you sure it's correct? What materials are you refering to?

Answer (score 1):

***update:***

Using `op = Function[r D[#, r] + Tan[phi] D[#, phi]];`, provided in the comments, in order to construct the requested differential equation

```
eq = I Nest[op, Psi[r, phi], 3] == 2 Psi[r, phi]*r^2/Cos[phi]^5 // Simplify
```

evaluates to

```
 4 I r^2 Psi[r,phi] Sec[phi]^5+6 Sec[phi]^2 Tan[phi]^2 (Psi^(0,2))[r,phi]+2 Tan[phi]^3 (Psi^(0,3))[r,phi]+2 r ((Psi^(1,0))[r,phi]+3 (1+Sec[phi]^2) Tan[phi] (Psi^(1,1))[r,phi]+3 Tan[phi]^2 (Psi^(1,2))[r,phi]+3 r (Psi^(2,0))[r,phi]+3 r Tan[phi] (Psi^(2,1))[r,phi]+r^2 (Psi^(3,0))[r,phi])==Sec[phi]^5 (-5 Sin[phi]+Sin[3 phi]) (Psi^(0,1))[r,phi]
```

Using the constraints introduced in the original version of this answer (`csts`, see below) and applying `NDSolve` on `{eq, Sequence@@csts}` with the original options and associated ranges for the variables produces a `NDSolve::ivone` message with text: "*Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.*".

***orig:***

Assuming the appropriate interpretation of the operator results in the following differential equation

```
Tan[phi]^3 (Psi^(0,3))[r,phi]+3 r Tan[phi]^2 (Psi^(0,2))[r,phi] (Psi^(1,0))[r,phi]+3 r^2 Tan[phi] (Psi^(0,1))[r,phi] (Psi^(2,0))[r,phi]+r^3 (Psi^(3,0))[r,phi]==2 r^2 Psi[r,phi] Sec[phi]^5
```

then the evaluation of the `NDSolve` produces a `NDSolve::ivone` message with text: "*Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.*".

code:

```
Power[Derivative[d__][h_][args__], n_] ^:= 
 With[{new = {d} /. {1 -> n}},
  Derivative[Sequence @@ new][h][args]
  ]

lhs = With[{h = Head[#], args = List @@ #},
  (args[[1]] D[#, args[[1]]] + Tan[args[[-1]]] D[#, args[[-1]]])^3 // Expand
 ] &@Psi[r, phi];

rhs = 2 Psi[r, phi]*r^2/Cos[phi]^5;

csts = {
  Psi[0, phi] == 1,
  0 == D[Psi[r, phi], r] /. r -> 0,
  10 == D[Psi[r, phi], {r, 2}] /. r -> 0,
  0 == D[Psi[r, phi], {r, 3}] /. r -> 0,

  Psi[r, 0] == 1,
  0 == D[Psi[r, phi], phi] /. phi -> 0
  }

NDSolve[
 {lhs == rhs, Sequence @@ csts},
 Psi,
 {r, 0, 3},
 {phi, 0, 3},
 MaxSteps -> Infinity,
 PrecisionGoal -> 1,
 AccuracyGoal -> 1, Method -> {
   "MethodOfLines",
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {
     "TensorProductGrid",
     "MinPoints" -> 32,
     "MaxPoints" -> 32,
     "DifferenceOrder" -> 2
     },
   Method -> {
     "Adams",
     "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 1
     }
   }
 ]
```